# How to fire an event only when a particular element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an alert `div`, which appears when a user clicks on a link. Now what I want to do is to hide that `div` when somebody clicks outside it. It by default has a `fadeoff` event attached, but I want the user be able to hide that div by clicking elsewhere.

I tried putting `$('body').click` inside the function call but its does not work. Please help, here is my JavaScript:

```
 var messageDiv = $('<div id="cannotDoDiv"></div>');
      $('body').append(messageDiv);  
      
      function appendDiv(this_element,msg)
      {
        var pos = this_element.offset();  
        var width = this_element.width();  
        messageDiv.css({  
          left: (pos.left - 20) + 'px',  
          top: pos.top + 30 + 'px'  
        });  
        $('#cannotDoDiv').fadeOut();
        $('#cannotDoDiv').html(msg).show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
        $('body').click(function(){
            $('#cannotDoDiv').hide();
        });
      }
    
    $("span#selfLike").click(function(){
        appendDiv($(this),'You cannot like your own post!');
    });
```

When I remove:

```
$('body').click(function(){
    $('#cannotDoDiv').hide();
});
```

from my function `$("span#selfLike").click` works fine, otherwise it is not being fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I think, I understood what you are trying.. see updated code below which

1. Uses `.one` to bind only once and unbinds after it is done..
2. Used on `fadeIn` callback so it will be binded only after the div is visible..

   ```
   //used call back function so it will be called only after it is 
   //completly visible
   $('#cannotDoDiv').html(msg).fadeIn("slow", function () {

        // below will be executed once and then unbind
        $(document).one('click', function(){  
          $('#cannotDoDiv').fadeOut();
       });

   });
   ```

Below is the complete code.. Updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gtwYZ/1/) here

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  var messageDiv = $('<div id="cannotDoDiv"></div>');

  $('body').append(messageDiv);  

 function appendDiv(this_element,msg)
 {
    var pos = this_element.offset();  
    var width = this_element.width();  
    messageDiv.css({  
      left: (pos.left - 20) + 'px',  
      top: pos.top + 30 + 'px'  
    });  
    $('#cannotDoDiv').hide();

    $('#cannotDoDiv').html(msg).fadeIn("slow", function () {

         $(document).one('click', function(){
           $('#cannotDoDiv').fadeOut();
        });

    });    

    $('#cannotDoDiv').one('click', function(){
       $('#cannotDoDiv').fadeOut();
    });
 }

$("span#selfLike").click(function(event){
    appendDiv($(this),'You cannot like your own post!');
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

 });
```

Note: This also closes when you click on the `$('#cannotDoDiv')` div. Add an click listener and stopPropogation if you don't want that to happen.

<s>Try `$(document).click(function(){` instead of body.</s>

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to do, because this attaches a `click` event to the `document` There will many clicks in general on that page and each time this event will be fired, which in a sense useless, What I want is to bind an event only when the div is visible

Comment: @Sachin See my updated code above.. which uses .one and fadeIn callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the propagation of the `click` event if it is fired on the `div` element so it doesn't reach the `document`, then bind a `click` event handler to the `document` element that hides the `div`:

```
$('#cannotDoDiv').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('#cannotDoDiv').hide();//you can now hide the div element because it was not clicked on but a click event fired
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

You could also un-bind the `click` event handler from the `document` once it fires to stop listening for the event if it isn't necessary to do so:

```
$(document).on('click.cannotDoDiv', function () {
    $('#cannotDoDiv').hide();//you can now hide the div element because it was not clicked on but a click event fired
    $(this).off('click.cannotDoDiv');
});
```

Since I used a namespace for the event this will not remove any other event handlers attached to the `document` element. Also, `.off()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same in this case as `.unbind()`.

Comment: I tried what you have written, and replaced `.on()` with `.bind()` and now the box is not being displayed